# SHM kinetic energy graph why starts from zero when at rest?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, harmonic-oscillator

I have following question:

> A particle is displaced from rest and released at time t = 0. It
> performs simple harmonic motion (SHM). Which graph shows the variation
> with time of the kinetic energy Ek of the particle?
> [image]

I am quit confused on why the D is the correct answer. I choose C which is wrong as I believe the velocity graph for SHM looks like this (with the displacement first goes up and goes down:

[image]

I think i should be the same as velocity graph as they are proportional to each other.

Also, from the logical perspective, the SHM converts all the kinetic energy to potential energy when reaches the leftmost/rightmost point and have highest kinetic energy at its equalibrium.

Any helps will be appreicated.

Comment: It says "released at time t = 0," so clearly it begins with zero velocity and zero kinetic energy

Comment: @RC_23, thanks for your response. I think I got a confusion here, isn't this indicates it starts at equalibrium poisition?

Comment: No: the question starts "A particle is displaced from rest and released". This means that it is NOT at its equilibrium when released.

Comment: @PhilipWood, thank you very much, this is my misconception. Then this is much clear to me now.

Comment: @James In addition,- if it would start at equilibrium position at $t=0$ - it would not move at all, because in that point potential energy is lowest possible. Unless particle is "punched" from equilibrium position with external force, but then motion chart would not be ideal SHM and this was not declared in problem definition, so this is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinetic energy is proportional to the square of velocity, so kinetic energy cannot be less than zero.  Also, kinetic energy is maximum when the particle is at equilibrium.  This problem describes the particle as being manually moved to a maximum position and released from rest.  The time during this displacement does not follow simple harmonic motion as energy is being added by the manual force.  Simple harmonic motion begins at the release, when only the conservative force is acting on the particle.  At this time, the particle is at rest.  Both velocity and kinetic energy are zero.  C would be correct if the particle were given an initial velocity and energy at equilibrium and then allowed to proceed out to its maximum displacement.  It could not be released from rest if this were the case.